# Can read() function on a connected socket return zero bytes?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming, runtime-error

I know that read() is a blocking call unless I make the socket non-blocking. So I expect read() call which requests 4K of data should return a positive value ( no of bytes read) or -1 on error ( possible connection reset by client etc). My question is: Can read() return '0' on any occasion?

I am handling the read() this way:

```
   if ((readval = read(acceptfd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) < 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
       buf[readval] = 0;
       //Do some thing with data  
    }
```

This code bombs if read() return zero and I know how to fix it. But is it possible for read() to return zero?

Comment: Have you considered reading the *man* page?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When a TCP connection is closed on one side read() on the other side returns 0 byte.

Comment: Shouldn't the read  return -1 with errno set to ECONNRESET? It is actually an error condition, if other side has closed the connection. Should we consider return of zero also as error condition?

Comment: @kumar: returning zero allows you to determine that an orderly shut down occurred, as opposed to a real error.

Comment: @Richard, Thanks. So I should consider zero as error condition and close the connected socket. Right?

Comment: Yes, you should close the connected socket. However it is not an error.

Comment: @kumar No, you should consider -1 as an error and 0 as a normal disconnect, and close the socket in either case.

Comment: just to add that if the buffer size you gave to read is 0, then the read will also return 0 even though the socket is not closed.

Comment: In this case, if I use epoll framework for monitoring fds, does it raise events such as EPOLLHUP or EPOLLERR in this particular case?