# How to detect that message is "terminated by closing the connection"

Tags: http, networking, network-programming, http-headers

HTTP specification (RFC2616) has the following phrase:

> If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and
>        has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
>        defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6),
>        unless the message is terminated by closing the connection.

How can I detect that the message is "terminated by closing the connection"? Is it enough to check the "Connection" field for value "close"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the RFC points to the TCP connection, when you read 0 bytes from the socket, the other side has closed the connection.

More:
[Can read() function on a connected socket return zero bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416944/can-read-function-on-a-connected-socket-return-zero-bytes)

Comment: If (Transfer-encoding present && not equal to identity && not connection is terminated by closing the connection) then I should decoded it as chunked-encoded. How can I detect last condition before peer is closed the connection?

Comment: I think that the idea of the "unless the message is terminated by closing the connection." phrase defines the exit condition of the chunk treatment (beacause a chunk may come in different packages, when a connection falls in chunk transfer state, it's in this state (appending the chunks) until the last chunk is detectd (length 0) or the connection is closed).. Something like If (Transfer-encoding present && not equal to identity){while (not end of chunk OR not end of connection){do the neccessary stuff with the chunk}};

Comment: This sounds very strange for me. I think that I shouldn't believe message body unless the last chunk is received.