# Server dies on `send` if client was closed with Ctrl+c

Tags: c, sockets, send

I cannot understand why this application dies on `send`. Here is the code for the server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define UNIX_PATH_MAX    108
#define SPATH "./sock"

int main() {
    int sfd, rv = 100, newfd;
    char b[100];
    char ok[3] = "ok\0";
    struct sockaddr_un sa;

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    strncpy(sa.sun_path, SPATH, UNIX_PATH_MAX);
    sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(sfd, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((newfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (rv != -1 && rv != 0) {
        rv = recv(newfd, b, 100, 0);

        printf("%s\n", b);

        sleep(3);

        printf("Send reply\n");
        send(newfd, ok, 3, 0);
        printf("Sent reply\n");
    }

    printf("END\n");
}
```

Unfortunately, if the client was forcefully closed using `Ctrl+C` as soon as it has sent the message, server will print (as last line):

`before send`

And then it dies without doing anything else. I tried to check errno or whatever else (including the call to `send` in an if statement), but it seems that it's `send` itself to cause the server to die. I've tryed with a `write` but it's the same.

I checked it's return code with bash, and it exits with return code 141, which I was unable to understand what it means.

If you want to try, here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define UNIX_PATH_MAX    108
#define SPATH "./sock"

int main() {
    int sfd, rv;
    char b[100];
    char ok[3];
    struct sockaddr_un sa;

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    strncpy(sa.sun_path, SPATH, UNIX_PATH_MAX);
    sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

    connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa));

    while (scanf("%s", b)) {
        send(sfd, b, 100, 0);

        recv(sfd, ok, 3, 0);

        printf("%s\n", ok);
    }

    printf("END\n");
}
```

Just compile both, run both and then kill the client with Ctrl+C just after the message has been sent.

Comment: But isn't that what is expected? After all the client to where the server was writing the data is no available anymore.

Comment: In the server, right after the while, why you didn't check the return value of recv() ??, also before using printf, you must nul terminate your newly receive string, for instance, b[rev] = 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782143/linux-socket-how-to-detect-disconnected-network-in-a-client-program

Comment: Nobody is going to 'just compile both, run both, and then kill the client'. You're expected to post the error messages, stack traces, etc here. This is not a free 2nd level help desk and you are not reporting a software bug in some vendor's code. -1

Comment: When a program's exit status is > 128, it means it was killed due to a signal `status-128`. If you look up the Unix signal list, you'll see that 13 is `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: @EJP, probably nobody had compiled it, but some people have read the whole question and not just the last line. I've posted the error code I get and they found a solution without even try to run the code. Thank you for your lesson on how to ask question on Stackoverflow, but unfortunately that was not my doubt. Cheers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you call `send()` on an already closed connection, the operating system may issue `SIGPIPE` to your process. Usually the default handler for `SIGPIPE` is to kill your process.

In order to prevent this from occurring, you can either ignore the signal (e.g., with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` or `sigignore(SIGPIPE)`), or you can pass the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` option to `send()`:

```
int send_result = send(newfd, ok, 3, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
if (send_result >= 0) {
    /* okay, but check if all your data got sent! */
    if (send_result < 3) /* ...do something */;
} else {
    switch (errno) {
    /* ... */
    case EPIPE:
        /* sending on a closed connection... */
    }
}
```

Now, instead of issuing `SIGPIPE`, the `send()` call will fail, and `errno` will be set to `EPIPE`.

Comment: There is no need to use errno, man page explicity says: ""The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown."" so, this MIGHT not even be a portable solution, testing for EPIPE.

Comment: We check `errno` if the result is less than `0`, indicating an error. The `0` return for orderly shutdown is with `recv()`. I haven't used a system where the `EPIPE` check was wrong for `send()` (Solaris, Linux, BSD, Winsock).

Comment: Richard Stevens - Unix network programming Third Edition, Chapter 5, section 5.3 TCP Echo Server. The author suggest testing for 0 and not EPIPE, in fact I was not able to find any evidence pointing the use of EPIPE. But of course, your answer seems to be correct.

Comment: but again I see no evidence of using EPIPE insted of checking for 0. Did you see Figure 5.14 tcpcliserv/str_cli11.c line 10, Richard is testing for 0. `if (Readline(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE) == 0)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. `MSG_NOSIGNAL` solved the problem. Now I can catch the error correctly.

Comment: @Kira: My last message may have been too terse. The code you cite is not dealing with `send()`, but for `recv()` (suggested by the fact that the API is called `Readline`, and the input buffer is called `recvline`). `EPIPE` and `SIGPIPE` are error conditions that occur for `send()`. Note that `recv()` errors would not induce `EPIPE` or `SIGPIPE`. Also, `recv()` return of `0` properly indicates that no more data is forthcoming. A `send()` return of `0` is an [edge case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3082032/315052) but not an error.

Comment: uh-huh, I learned I lot. I realized it is better to use recv(2)/send(2) instead of read(2)/write(2) when dealing with sockets, although, whenever possible, the use of writev(2)/readv(2) is a lot better than a simple recv/send. Knowing how to handle these functions is crucial, your answer lightened my sight, despite the fact I wasn't totally agree with your answer at the time

Answer (score 0):

in the server side, check if the client closed the connexion:

```
rv = recv(newfd, b, 100, 0);
if(rv<=0) {
        if(!rv) {
             fprintf(stderr, "conn. closed.");
        } else {
              perror("recv");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: `!rv` isn't correct. You must check for `rv == 0` to detect EOS, and -1 to detect an error.

Comment: @EJP  wait!, 0 evaluate to false, anything else evaluate to TRUE, if rv==0, then !rv will evaluate to TRUE and the fprintf function will be executed. Asterisk CodingStyle explicitly suggest using !variable instead of variable==0. man your -1 is so incorrect.

Comment: This will not prevent the observed crash from occurring if the server is sending when the client has already been killed.

Comment: @Kira It's a trick, and a confusing one, as this discussion shows. The return value is documented as -1, 0, or a positive integer, and that is what you should test. There is no such recommendation in the coding style you cite.

Comment: @EJP I'm so sorry for the bad citation; human mistake, I meant, Mozilla Coding Style, section: C/C++ practices. Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Coding_Style very easy to check. "...Use (x) or (!x) instead..."